# Scraping infinite scrolling pages using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, data-science

I want help in scraping infinite scrolling pages. For now, I have entered `pageNumber = 100`, which helps me in getting the name from 100 pages.

But I want to crawl all the pages till the end. As the page has infinite scrolling and being new to scrapy I am unable to do the same. I am trying this for the past 2 days.

```
class StorySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'story-spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.storytel.com/in/en/categories/3-Crime?pageNumber=100']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.gridBookTitle'):
            item = {
                'name': quote.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            }
            yield item
```

The original link is https://www.storytel.com/in/en/categories/1-Children. I see that the pageNumber variable is inside script tag, if it helps to find the solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you search the XPath like `<link rel="next" href=''>` 
you will found the pagination option. With the help of you can add the pagination code.

here is some example of the pagination page.

```
 next_page = xpath of pagination

 if len(next_page) !=0:
       next_page_url = main_url.join(next_page
       yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

It will helps you.